# Reflection map baking

Tags: game-engine, texture-baking

I have an Island and water on which i want to add fake reflections, I know I have to bake a map and use it as difuse color through reflection mapping but how do i create the map ?

[image]

This shows my render blender settings from wich i want to bake the reflection map to use in the bge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really my area of expertise, but depending on what you want you could try baking a texture from a glossy sphere.

1. Create a new UV Sphere, you may want to make it an all quads mesh
   first by removing the top and bottom vertex, then selecting the
   first open edge loop, and extruding it, then scale it to zero so
   that all vertex merge at the center, but don't remove doubles.
2. Mark a seam along one of its vertical loops and select one random
   face. Now Unwrap it using the *Active Quads* option. In the image
   editor it should wield a perfect orthogonal grid mesh.
3. You can now assign a perfectly glossy material to the sphere and use
   it to bake an environment map of your island.

I have not tried it myself, but it should work; I used a similar technique under Cycles render to create a cube map environment

Comment: Ok this is what i needed to know, now where am i to place the sphere in the scene and at what scale ? I'm having wrong reflections, i tried to en globe the scene, then i tried to scale it down and place it in the middle of the scene, i have tried also to flip normals but nothing will do so i think i'm missing something important.

Comment: Have in mind that baked reflections are always an approximation, they are never fully correct, not even from the exact point they were baked from. You can reduce visual errors by placing the sphere in a place as close as possible to the final render or image position, or if it's a game or real time user controlled environment, place it at the most common user eye height and centered somewhere in the user accessible area, or close to the most common view point.

Comment: It is always going to look more distorted the further away you are from the bake point. You'll have to test what scale will look best yourself, but I would say maybe around camera size, if it's a metric units scene perhaps a 1m diameter sphere.